# Creating a flow graph in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis-3, flow-map

I attempting to make flow graph in QGIS 3.4, some thing like [image]

I have found several 'ways to do it' in QGIS 2.xx eg [QGIS2.0 method](https://anitagraser.com/2016/12/30/new-style-flow-map-arrows)

I known its possible to get a line with arrows by just change the line type.

But I am not sure how to get a curved line

The Arrow and Flow mapper plugin only seems to be a QGIS 2.xxx feature.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't comment but have a look here if you still need to do this:
https://anitagraser.com/2019/05/04/flow-maps-in-qgis-no-plugins-needed/